# Can't clean install ubuntu 14.10+

Tags: boot

I can clean install 14.04 as many times as I like. 
I can clean install any other flavour of Linux as I like (debian, mint, bhodi etc etc). 
I can't install 14.10 or newer of ubuntu or their derivatives like "studio" kubuntu 14.10+ also out of the question.......

When I try to clean install from disc (both downloaded and shop bought) I get the initramfs fault, also if I try over the air upgrade same happens...

I have bought new dvd drive and I have bought new ssd ........ just anything newer than 14.04 triggers the initramfs.....

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. You have not provided any info about the hardware or the architecture of the distros you are trying to install, reducing the possibility to receive helpful feedback.

Comment: lol, sorry, just a desktop with AMD chip 64bit basic cheap parts, onboard graphics etc etc...... everything works lovely untill I try to upgrade... ram problem or bios???????

Comment: When you say "I get the initramfs fault", I think you mean the Busybox prompt.  What errors do you get before the lines that begin with "Busybox" and "(initramfs)"

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved but I dont know why......I saw something some where (can't remember who or why) that made me get into the bios and turn iommu off. I then installed 16.04 with no problems......mystery to me....lolol
Thanks for the try Martin, I have a screen shot...............

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtCXM.jpg)